# Displaying multiple plots at once with persp3d

Tags: r, plot, rgl

I have got many plots of spectral data with the `persp3d`function and with `open3d` I am able to open them in different windows (see below).
My question is if there is a possibility to open them up in the same window, by giving a number of rows and columns?
 And if so, is there furthermore the possibility that the rotation I do with the mouse applies to all the displayed plots?

Below I have already found a way to open them up in different windows without overlapping so I can examine them separately (in the code: "t_*number*" and "w" are vectors corresponding to the "F*number*" matrix respectively).

I tried doing it with the `plot3d` and the `mfrow3d` command, resulting in one window with many plots (like the answer posted to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14712497/plot3d-having-two-plots-at-once), but the plot3d function is not capable of giving sufficient data plots (the spectral data does not look alike the same data as in `persp3d`).

```
   open3d(
    persp3d(t_134, w, F134, col = col,
               xlab = "", ylab = "", zlab = "", main = "F134", 
      )
    )
    open3d(
     persp3d(t_135, w, F135, col = col,
               xlab = "", ylab = "", zlab = "", main = "F135"
      )
    )
    [...]
```

How can I plot them in one window and rotate them all the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of `open3d( ... plot function ...)` is wrong.  The arguments to `open3d` control characteristics of the window.  You shouldn't be passing `rgl` plotting results to it.

To open multiple plots in a single window, after calling `open3d` properly, call `mfrow3d(rows, cols, sharedMouse = TRUE)` to set up an array of plots.  They will all respond to mouse actions in any of them.

For example:

```
library(rgl)
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- rnorm(100)
z <- rnorm(100)
open3d()
mfrow3d(2, 2, sharedMouse = TRUE)
plot3d(x, y, z, col = "red")
plot3d(x, y, z, col = "green")
plot3d(x, y, z, col = "blue")
plot3d(x, y, z, col = "yellow")
```

[image: screenshot]

There are other functions if you don't want an array of equal-sized plots:  `layout3d`, etc.